# NodeJs: modular system

Tags: javascript, node.js, model-view-controller, express

I have such file structure in my node.js app:

- app

  - models

    - user
    - book
  - controllers

    - user
    - book
  - views

    - user
    - book

I want to make my app modular. How can I interact with `book` controller from `user` controller? I know about `require(...)`, but is there any smart way to do it? So my target is to make many modules (user, book, article, news, etc.), and easily on/off any of these without affecting others (like PHP CMS - Joomla, Wordpress, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

I am from django background so I find sails.js (their site is giving internal error) and geddy quite usable.
You can use express with a template engine(jade) to make it somewhat MVC to start with and keep Model files separately in another folder.

Maybe this will help.A good discussion somewhat related to your question.
[which NodeJS MVC framework currently has the best mix of maturity and ease of use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9744798/which-nodejs-mvc-framework-currently-has-the-best-mix-of-maturity-and-ease-of-us)

Just making the file structure look like an MVC project, I am afraid, won't serve your purpose unless it is enforced by the framework.

Comment: Last line of your answer should be bolded. In general, I would look at inter-controller communication as improper in an MVC app. However, angular, for instance, actually allows (encourages?) nested controllers which can then broadcast or emit events up or down their scope chain respectively to child/parent controllers.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a modular framework for building a node app you may want to check out Kraken by the folks over at Paypal.

project home: http://krakenjs.com/

github: https://github.com/paypal/kraken-js

**Structure of a kraken project**

> /config Application and middleware configuration
>
> /controllers Routes and logic
>
> /lib Custom developer libraries and other code
>
> /locales Language specific content bundles
>
> /models Models
>
> /public Web resources that are publicly available
>
> /public/templates Server and browser-side templates
>
> /tests Unit and functional test cases
>
> index.js Application entry point

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the Scott Puleo answer,  Kraken JS helped me get MVC infrastructure right, but it doesn't have option to implement plugin architecture, that you asked in your question.

In kraken js, easiest way to implement that is

1.Create '/plugins-folder' under /lib to accommodate all your plugin js files.

2.Create index.js file under '/plugins-folder' and add following code to it.

```
require('fs').readdirSync(__dirname+ '/').forEach(function(file) {
  if (file.match(/.+\.js/g) !== null ) {
  var name = file.replace('.js', '');
  exports[name] = require(__dirname+'/'+ file);
  }
});
```

3. In the files, where you need plugins declare the following

```
var plugins = require('./plugins-folder');
```

4. Now you can get your plugin just by accessing like below

```
plugins['plugin-name']
```